# Can I leave my game running with no consequences

Tags: kittens-game

I have been playing kitten game and I have noticed that if I leave the game for a year the game runs fine and no kittens starve. Is there a consequence to this or can I just leave my game running to get resources?

Comment: You just accidentally happened to notice something about leaving a game open for a _year_?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit an *in-game* year.

Comment: @immibis: Oh. How long is that in real life?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit IIRC it's 800 seconds. So 13 minutes and 20 seconds.

Comment: @immibis: Well never mind then :D looool

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on how far into the game you are. If your catnip production is high enough such that a -90% cold winter comes along and your kittens don't starve, than there are no negative consequences. But, it's possible you'll miss out on some advantages - based on how far you are into the game.

At the very beginning of the game (before Astronomical events) you won't 'miss out' on anything, but your resource limits aren't likely to be high enough to make this a useful strategy.

Once Astronomical Events and Hunters are unlocked, you'll have to pay more attention to the game if you want to make sure you aren't maxing out your catpower (thereby losing valuable ivory and furs, which equals more production) or missing Astronomical events - which give you science and a starchart.

At the end of the game, once you have a Mint (or a few) (which produces furs and ivory) and have the upgrade that automatically registers Astronomical Events, the only thing you have to watch out for is maxing out your resource pools.

TLDR; The only things you have to worry about are negative producing resources, click required resources (Astronomical Events and Hunting), and maxing out any resource pools.

Comment: Even if the OP misses the events, I still consider this strategy superior to pausing at any phase of the game. The possible events or hunts are lost either way, but when you return to the computer, you at least have full warehouses. Even if the kittens die in the middle, it can be better (unless you are shooting for achievement). The only superior strategy is to sit at the computer all the time, but this is suboptimal for out-of-game reasons.

Comment: @rumtscho I agree, I leave my kittens to fend for themselves often. Sometimes when I come back my catpower (and other resources are full), my furs are empty and I've missed a hundred events. But, I can build nearly any building I want.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you'll be missing. They are events that you need to click (Astronomical events) that you'll miss the science from them.

There might be other events like those but I'm not that far out to know but I suspect there might be.

You won't be able to send hunters to hunt and gain the happiness bonus from the resources they get as that need a click to do.

If you are sure your catnip reserve will never get to 0 even with all seasons being cold ones, it should be safe kitten-wise.